# Swift Function With Optional Generic Parameter

Tags: swift, generics

I am trying to make a generic URLRequest maker function but my implementation is giving me an error when there is no body. How can I fix this?

```
guard let request: URLRequest = RequestMaker.requestMaker(url: followUser, method: .get) else { return false }
```

Gives this error: `Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred`

```
class RequestMaker {
    static func makeRequest<T: Encodable>(
        url: String,
        method: HTTPMethod,
        _ body: T? = nil
    ) -> URLRequest? {
        guard let url: URL = .init(string: url) else { return nil }
        var request: URLRequest = .init(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = method.rawValue
        request.addAuthorizationHeader()
        request.timeoutInterval = 15.0
                
        if let body: T = body {
            request.httpBody = try? JSONEncoder().encode(body)
        }
        
        return request
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be the most convenient to just create another non-generic overload, and make `body` not optional in the original overload.

Call the generic overload in the new overload so you don't duplicate code, and pass `nil` to `body`, but cast it to a specific `Encodable` type first, so that `T` can be inferred.

```
static func makeRequest(
    url: String,
    method: HTTPMethod
) -> URLRequest? {
    // here I used String, but any Encodable type would work
    makeRequest(url: url, method: method, nil as String?)
}
```